# How to use _beginthreadex in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to create a worker thread using `_beginthreadex()`. However, the compiler says:

```
Error   1   error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression
```

Here is my code:

.cpp file

```
hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &Udp_Thread, NULL, 0, &threadID ); // Function caller in main()

unsigned __stdcall CUdpSocket::Udp_Thread(void *arguments) 
{
    ...
}
```

.h file

```
public:
unsigned __stdcall Udp_Thread(void *arguments);
```

I am following exactly as what MSDN did but it doesn't work in my program. What should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C2276: The compiler found a problem with the syntax to create a pointer-to-member.

You need to specify the class scope.

Further `_beginthreadex` takes a function pointer not a member function pointer. So you must pass the address of a *static* function.

Use this one:

```
classs CUdpSocket 
{
public:
    unsigned static __stdcall Udp_Thread(void *arguments);
}

 // Function caller in main()
 hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &CUdpSocket::Udp_Thread, NULL, 0, &threadID );
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Udp_Thread is a member of a class. In this case it must be static, otherwise the prototype of the function is not what _beginthreadex expects, since it has an additional, implied member, which is pointer this.

Comment: @harper: Yes, it will. The error is explicitly that the function is non-static.

Comment: @harper, depends on the compiler; thy VC6 and this &CUdpSocket::Udp_Thread won't compile (if I remember correctly). :)

Comment: @Marius: Just checked with VC6. It compiles fine with this VC++ version as well as with newer versions of VC++.

Comment: oh then, by bad. been some while since I worked with VC++, don't know why I remembered it didn't compile

Comment: @Marius: You had to change from VC6 to VC7. With VC6 you could omit the CUdpSocket:: prefix.